# Word for saying product is good after buying it even if it's really not

Tags: single-word-requests

When someone buys a product that's really not that good, perhaps overpriced, and he/she then tells everyone how good it is, to justify the purchase (to him/herself).

*Is there a name for the phenomenon?*

Example: Someone buys the Beats headphones, finds that they're really bad and cheaply made, but starts telling friends how great they are and what a bargain it was.

Comment: The nearest I've come up with are "Making the best of a bad job" and "Trying to make a silk purse out of a sow's ear."  I'm sure there's a better one.

Comment: Single-word request? If you'll accept multiple words why not amend your tag? You'll get more responses.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Google turns up [this wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post-purchase_rationalization) which currently reads:

> ***Post-purchase rationalization***, also known as *Buyer's Stockholm Syndrome*, is a cognitive bias whereby someone who has purchased an expensive product or service overlooks any faults or defects in order to justify their purchase. It is a special case of choice-supportive bias.

This is the answer to your question, is it not?

Comment: "Post-purchase rationalization", that works. thanks.

Comment: This can result from a subconscious attempt to reduce **cognitive dissonance**

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like an attempt to ***save face***.

> To take an action or make a gesture intended to preserve one's reputation or honour.

Wiktionary.org

Comment: That's it, +1 Charon.